# Moving an image with 360° angle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, parallax

I am trying to make an image move 360° (not rotate) back it's course, but so far I was able to move only to a specific direction, if I add left & bottom course, then the image going diagonal to left & bottom. Here are the properties:

#### CSS

```
#circle{
    background:red; 
    border-radius:100px; 
    height:100px; width:100px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

#### JavaSript

```
(function() {

var speed = 10, 

  moveBox = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById("circle"),
        left = el.offsetLeft,
        moveBy = 3;     

    el.style.left = left + moveBy + "px";

        if(left > 200){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    };

    var timer = setInterval(moveBox, speed);

}());
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id='circle'></div>
```

#### JsFiddle [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E3peq/)

The problem is looping back the red circle, I want it to move to left > bottom > right > up
in a circular manner.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Try setting `top` rather than `bottom`.

Comment: I have tried with top, but the circle goes in a left+top position, it does not even come back.

Comment: like this [http://jsfiddle.net/E3peq/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/E3peq/5/)? or move to each corner?

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Thanks so much. That was amazing. I was actually looking for anti clock-wise solution for this. If you had answer I would accept, or answer for `+1` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Math.sin and Math.cos to describe the circle: http://jsfiddle.net/E3peq/7/

```
(function() {
    var speed = 10, 
        moveX = 0.1,
        moveY = 0.1,
        increment = 0.1,
        amp = 10,
        moveBox = function(){
            var el = document.getElementById("circle"),
                left = el.offsetLeft,
                top = el.offsetTop;

            moveX += increment;
            moveY += increment;

            var moveXBy = Math.cos(moveX) * amp;
            var moveYBy = Math.sin(moveY) * amp;

            el.style.left = (left + moveXBy) + "px";
            el.style.top = (top + moveYBy) + "px";

            if(left > 200){
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        };

        var timer = setInterval(moveBox, speed);

}());
```

Edit: Abraham's answer in the comments is actually a lot nicer looking than this...

Comment: Thanks, this works fine too. Only problem is that it stops after a certain loop, how can I make this infinit?